# Sum of ten 0.1 floats is not equal to 1

Tags: objective-c, math, floating-point

I'm adding up some `float`s in a loop.
I expected that when `i` reaches 9, the sum will be equal to 1, and `NSLog(@"EXTRA: %f", sum);` will be executed. It is never executed... what is going on here?

Here is my code:

```
float number = 0.1;
float sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    sum += number;

    if (sum == 1) {
        NSLog(@"EXTRA: %f", sum);
    }
    NSLog(@"%f", sum);
}
```

Comment: Try 0.1+0.2 and if you know binary, write out 0.1 in binary.

Comment: Haven't done any binary in years

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The binary value of `1/10` is like the Denary value of `1/3` - it reccurs. In fact, the value of `1/10` stored in the variable is `0.0001100110011001100110011...`.

But the length of this number is limited by the `float` length, or a 32 / 64 bit OS.

So when I add `0.000110011` to `0.000110011` I get `0.001100110` which is not quite `2/10`, the same as `0.333333` + `0.333333` =! `2/3` - it equals `0.66666`.

This is happening 9 times, and so `1/10 * 10` in binary doesn't equal `1`, it's 0.111111111 which equals `0.998046875` - a long way off `1`.

To more decimal places (e.g. 30) `0.000110011001100110011001100110 * 1010` = `0.111111111111111111111111111100` or `0.999999996274709701538085937500`. Which is not quite `1`.

Comment: Please don't go editing lots of questions just to add pronouns, it spams the front page with all of your changes.